# Collapse nested array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to take an array with shape `(N,)`, and `dtype=object`, of arrays that all have the same shape, `shape`, and create an array with `shape == (N,) + shape`. I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to do this. Here's an example.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.empty(4, dtype=object)
array[:] = [np.ones([3, 2])]
array = np.array(array.tolist())
print array.dtype
# float64
print array.shape
# (4, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Was going to suggest `concatenate`, but really your solution seems already best to me. If you know the dtype, you could give that instead of using `.tolist()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the shape of your inner arrays (here, `(3,2)`), you could simplify the whole process as

```
subshape = (3,2)
a = np.empty(tuple([N,]+list(subshape)), dtype=object)
a[:] = np.ones(subshape)
```

That will let you avoid unnecessary conversions to/from lists.

---

Now, assuming you have a `(N,)` object array `a` where each element is a `subshape` float array, you could do:

```
a = np.vstack(a)
a.shape = [N,] + list(subshape)
```

or more simply:

```
a = np.array(a.tolist(), dtype=float)
```

the `.tolist` conversion might not be very efficient, though.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I already have an array with shape=(N,) and dtype=object, I want to turn it into an array of shape=(N, 3, 2) and dtype=float.